# Polymer How can I get core-item>core-button to access parent core-list model

Tags: polymer

I'm learning polymer and I've run into an issue where I have a core-list iterating on a datasource templating a paper-item that houses a core-icon-button.

```
<core-list id="list" fit>
            <template>
                <paper-item flex class="row {{ {selected: selected} | tokenList }}">
                  <core-icon-button id="settings" 
                                    icon="settings" 
                                    on-tap={{settingTap}}>
                  </core-icon-button>

                  {{model.Name}}
                </paper-item>
            </template>
          </core-list>
```

The problem I am having is that on my buttons' on-tap function I need the parent items' model. Is there a "polymer way" to do what I am describing? Or do I have to extend

Comment: perhaps you could use `<template bind='{{model}}'>`?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <polymer-element name='cust-list'>
        <template>
            <style>
            </style>        
            <core-list id="list" fit data={{models}}>
                <template>                
                    <paper-item flex class="row {{ {selected: selected} | tokenList }}">
                    <core-icon-button id="settings" icon="settings" on-tap={{settingTap}}></core-icon-button>
                        {{model.name}}
                    </paper-item>
                </template> 
            </core-list>
        </template>

        <script>
            Polymer('cust-list', {
      models: [{name: "test1"}, {name: "test2"}],
      settingTap: function(e,d,s) {
          console.log(s.templateInstance.model.model);
      }
    });
        </script>
    </polymer-element>

    <cust-list></cust-list>
```